# Is there an effective way to validate an image source url in node?

Tags: node.js

I am using Node to get Instagram images and have come across an edge case I am interested in solving. While using the oembed API call, I can then get `thumbnail_url`. 
In my service, I return the image url and move on. The issue here is, for certain permalinks (carousel/albums), this `thumbnail_url` loads with a 5xx Instagram Error.

What I would like to do is to verify the image url loads an image, and if not, do something else instead of returning it.

I know what the "something else" is. My problem is that the url I get back from the oembed call is indeed a valid url, so I don't need to validate that. I need to validate the url loads as expected.

My initial thought process was to do something like but I have never tried to verify an image source url before, I've always just tried to get the url in the first place:

```
function urlTester(url) {
    request(url, (error, response, body) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log('URL does not load');
      } else {
        console.log('URL loads image!');
      }
    })
}
```

Comment: Does the target API support `HEAD` requests or another way to check resource is there w/o transferring whole image back to your server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the urls are always valid, and you only need to check for the actual response, you are correct.

**(Vanilla) Request Example :**

```
request(url,function(error, response, body){
 if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
  /*  RESPONSE SUCCESS  */
 }else{
  /*  RESPONSE ERROR    */
 }
})
```

If you want to go on further and verify that the response indeed contains an image you can use  : `response.headers['content-type']`

```
if(((response.headers['content-type']).match(/(image)+\//g)).length != 0){
  /* It contains 'image/' as the content type */
}else{
  /* no match with 'image/' */
}
```

---

You can also try using [`request-image-size`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-image-size)

> Detects image dimensions via request instead of Node.js native
>   http/https, allowing for options and following redirects by default.
>   It reduces network traffic by aborting requests as soon as image-size
>   is able to obtain the image size.

It will return an error if the response is not a valid image :

> Since version 2.0.0 it returns an ES6 native Promise that resolves
>   with the size object or rejects with an Error. Requires Node.js v4+.

Comment: Thanks @EMX we were both right, I think I was doing it wrong the first time. See my answer below to detail what I've done, but I'm accepting your answer as it covers exactly what is needed.

Comment: Sadly, above technic doesn't work on node.js for some URL like https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/0*cI5eoFps4thgr01A.jpeg content-type is [ 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' ]. Interestingly on frontend content-type is image.

Answer (score 0):

As @EMX pointed out, I was headed in the right direction. Here is what I ended up doing:

```
function testUrl(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(url, function(error, response, body) {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
      resolve(response.statusCode);
    })
  })
}
```

If the statusCode !== 200, then I can move on as initially required.